# Working with Soundcloud API

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, soundcloud

I am working with an app we are developing and I am getting a 404 on Soundclouds link.

//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js ?

please advise as this is the link they provide to connect

Answer (score 0):

You should contact them as the link to the JS is clearly not loading.  You need a new URL.

You can load http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js in your web browser to see that it is not available.

It is possible that you are not authorized to view this file and it is displaying the 404 message hiding the not authorized condition.  If this is the case you will need to get authentication information.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted them. I am hoping it is solved soon.

Comment: The [WayBack Machine has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20140227162814/https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js). It might be useful in a pinch, but I wouldn't use it for production.

Comment: I don't know about the stability of the code in the file showdev mentions, but if it is stable, you could always copy the JS to your local server so there isn't any worry of the URL changing or the file disappearing.

Comment: We are looking into that and that may help us out until they get it resolved.